# Qt qrc warning: qrc_icons.cpp: not a directory

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

There is already existing project compiled with CMake and there are multiple warnings like this one:

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/project.dir/App/main.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: /home/project/build/qrc_icons.cpp: not a directory
```

Searching for qrc files before build gives me only one qrc file: `icons.qrc`. Before build it is referenced only once at CmakeLists.txt:

```
./CMakeLists.txt:qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/icons.qrc")
```

`icons.qrc` contents:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/resources">
        <file>icons/example1.png</file>
        <file>icons/example2.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```